# Split a String at every 1000th comma in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am not able to split the string for every 1000th comma in a string using regular expression. We are able to split for every 3rd comma in string but not for 1000th comma.

```
String data = "0,0,1,2,4,5,3,4,6......";
String[] array = data.split("(?<=\\G\\d+,\\d+,\\d+),"); //Magic :) 
// to reveal magic see explanation below answer
for(String s : array){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: why with regex? And ask yourself: "Do I understand what the regex in the question does?"

Comment: Try to find the index of 1000th comma using a loop, then do a substring.

Comment: How is this question is a duplicate! Unless of course you think the OP should place `\\d+,` 1000 times within his/her regex string (which I believe wont work either). Read the question. Has anyone tried it to accomplish this with the accepted answer within the duplicate? I think the OP initially got the code there.

Comment: @DevilsHnd look at the second, third, etc. answers. The data is also a dupe, just the end result is different

Comment: It is the end result the OP wants to accomplish...split on every 1000th delimiter. Granted, some of the other answers may accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the regex you're looking for:

```
 (\w*,){3}\K\S+

  \w             Matches a word ([a-zA-Z0-9_])
  \w*            Matches 0 or infinite number of words...
  \w*,           ... Followed by a coma
 (\w*,){n}       Match this group, n times
          \K     Reset the starting point of the match after the n elements
            \S+  Matches any word after the (n-1)th coma
```

Where `n` is the number of elements, plus 1. So in your case, it would be `1001`.

With that being said, `regex` is probably not the right tool for this :)

Comment: `\K` is not a valid token in Java

Comment: Good point @ctwheels - Has this been added to Java Regular Expressions? It is however a premium feature of .NET, Perl or PCRE.

Comment: @DevilsHnd it's still not a feature in Java unfortunately.

Comment: I realize this, however the author of this post does not and still...it was up-voted by someone. ;)